# Where is the message user not in sudoers created?

Tags: 14.04, sudo

I get emails when user's try to do sudo on my server but where is this message actually generated and emailed out from?

Subject: * SECURITY information for localhost *

localhost : Jun 18 16:55:42 : username: user NOT in sudoers ; TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/../ izard ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tee signin_wizard.module

Comment: Obviously, it is sent from the machine where the incorrect `sudo` command was run, though it can pass through other mail servers on the way to its destination. This is only a comment because I have a feeling this is not your real question.

Comment: I think the answer you're after is "sudoers" and if you `man sudoers` and search (press forward-slash then type [partial] keyword) for "mailto" you'll find about 5 different config variables that relate to emailing. `mail_no_user` is possible the flag your interested in.